# SQL query with count and group by in three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on an sql query where I have three tables posts, users and comments. I want to display all posts with its users and number of comments on this. I have following query but it is giving me wrong result:

```
SELECT 
c.userid, count(c.userid), p.postid 
FROM comments c, posts p 
where c.userid = p.userid group by c.userid
```

In addition to above query I also require firstname and lastname from users table.

Comment: you say you have 3 tables but you only have 2 in this query.

Comment: I am not getting correct data for two tables, only when I get this I will be adding data from third table

Comment: In general, you should GROUP BY *all* unaggregated columns in your SELECT clause (so, postid and userid in this case). And don't use comma-join syntax; it went out with the dinosaurs.

Comment: which user information are you trying to get?  the one who created the post or the one's who commented on the post?

Comment: I need user who created the post and number of comment on the post also text of the post

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
 SELECT 
    u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname,p.post, p.postid, 
    count(c.userid) totalcoments  -- may be c.commentid
    FROM users u 
    JOIN posts p  ON p.userid=u.userid
    LEFT JOIN  comments c OM c.postid=p.postid
    GROUP BY u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname,p.post, p.postid
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    postid
    , p.userid 
    , COALESCE((
        SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM comments WHERE postid = p.id 
    ), 0 ) AS cnt_postid
    , COALESCE( ( SELECT CONCAT( firstname, ' ', lastname ) FROM users WHERE userid = p.userid ), 'N/A' ) AS NAME
FROM posts p 
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.postid = p.id
GROUP BY postid 
ORDER BY postid
```

you are probably getting the same amount of count because you not using a group by.

`GROUP BY` must always be used when using aggregate function. What the group by does is that it will select all unique posts and the the count will return the number of users for that one unique post

Comment: This is true. Forgot to add that in the description. Thanks

Comment: I tried this but it is giving wrong count (cnt) values, also few of userid are NULL

Comment: Thanks Allen, it is working for me now. But I am getting first row with NULL or 0 or N/A content.

Comment: also I am not getting all postid in the query. I should be getting all postid from database

Comment: Yes that is because I have c.userid, it should be p.userid because I just read in your comment that you want the post's username. That would take care of the NULL

Sorry I didn;t even know that I had save the changes. Wanted to cancel. The left join of the users is what is making the postid not showing. I will change the answer back. :)

Please see changes above